# saving one many to many field from one django model to another

Tags: django

I have the following code;

```
# check whether it's valid:
if form.is_valid():
    travel = form.save(commit=False)
    travel.user = request.user
    travel.save()
    form.save_m2m()


    travel_2 = Travel()
    travel_2.from_city = travel.to_city
    travel_2.to_city = travel.from_city
    travel_2.from_when = travel.to_when
    travel_2.commission = travel.commission
    travel_2.user = travel.user
    travel_3 = travel_2.save()
```

that basically saves one travel object and then copies that travel object to another travel object ( travel_2 )

how do I save the many to many field "category" from travel to travel_2?

that many to many field is being set in the line:

```
form.save_m2m()
```

Answer (score 0):

Really, we need to see what your models look like in order to given a proper answer, but this should help you work things out. Let's use the classes as defined in the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

Then in the Django shell we can create some model instances.

```
p1 = Publication(title='The Python Journal')
p1.save()
p2 = Publication(title='Science News')
p2.save()
p3 = Publication(title='Science Weekly')
p3.save()
a1 = Article(headline='Django lets you build Web apps easily')
a1.save()
a2 = Article(headline='Django lets you build Web apps easily part 2')
a2.save()
```

And finally add some publications to the article. `a1` is now related to `p1`, `p2` and `p3`. This step is already complete when you save the form.

```
a1.publications.add(p1, p2)
a1.publications.add(p3)
a1.save()
```

If we want to give an article all the publications that another article has.

```
a2.publications = a1.publications.all()
a2.save()
```

Or if we want to copy the `article_set` that is a property of `p1`.

```
p2.article_set = p1.article_set.all()
p2.save()
```

Which of these two methods you will need depends on whether your travel object has the M2M relationship (like `Article`) or whether it has the reverse M2M relationship (like `Publication`).